# Can a local glassfish on windows be configured to work with a remote db2 on UNIX?

Tags: windows, unix, db2, glassfish

I am trying to make db2 work in glassfish with no luck at all. I've read the documentation, but no matter what I do I end up stuck with an error when I do a ping. I put the jar files for the db2 driver and connectivity in the classpath prefix, added them to the lib directory of the domain and no go. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're not posting sample configuration so that we can have a look, that's what's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry and I do apologise about that. Honestly, I wouldn't even know where to start. Please visit my latter comments. I hope those offer more information. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about the datasource creation. Did you create a datasource ?

Here is how you can create one, in the domain.xml file in conf dir of your domain.

```
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/<YOUR_DS_NAME_HERE>" object-type="user" pool-name="<YOUR_POOL_NAME_HERE>">
<description><DESCRIPTION></description>
</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource" fail-all-connections="true" idle-timeout-in-seconds="140" is-connection-validation-required="true" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="YOUR_POOL_NAME_HERE>" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="32" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="0" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
<description><YOUR_POOL_NAME_HERE_DESCRIPTION></description>
<property name="user" value="<USERNAME>"/>
<property name="password" value="<PASSWORD>"/>
<property name="portNumber" value="<PORTNUMBER>"
<property name="databaseName" value="DATABASE_NAME"/>
<property name="serverName" value="<SERVER_NAME>"/>
<property name="driverType" value="4"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

You can also copy the jar files in the $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib dir.

Comment: Thank you for ur replies.I have checked the domain1.xml file before posting, having found this: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=27389 I have created the data source.I have put: db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_javax.jar, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar in domains\domains1 in lib and ext.At ur suggestion in $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib as well.Also, set classpath prefix AND native library path prefix to point to C:\db2s\[said *.jar]. I keep getting no db2jcct2 in java.library.path, even though the file is in C:\db2s and NLP is set to both db2jcc2.dll && db2jcct2.dll. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you ping your datapool from the admin console ? What exception do you get ? Can you paste the stacktrace from server.log ?

Comment: Ok, yes. Thank you!I finally realised what went wrong. First time I created the datasource, manually changed the driver type in the domain.xml file, but the .jar files were in all the wrong places. Second time I restarted from scratch (new connection pool, new data source) I had the .jar files in the right place (directly in the GLASSFISH_HOME/lib as you've stated), but forgot to do the manual changes in the xml. Brilliant me. *facepalm* Hopefully, someone else will learn from this. So, thank you again so very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you again. I just feel the need to emphasize again, that the driverType part MUST be added by hand in the domain.xml file in order for this to work.